# "The shop has been.open the whole day/for the whole day"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction, grammaticality

Please correct me if I am wrong. My interpretation is "The shop has been open the whole day" (as in it was open but now it is closing)

The Shop has been open the whole day= "The shop has been open for the whole day (with or with out "for" will not make a different(The shop is still open)

Comment: Side note: It should be, "The shop ..." You need an article.

Comment: Cheers.I correct it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning is the same whether or not "for" is used. Either way the sentence would be used around the end of the day, and means the shop has been open continuously since the start of the day (often 9.00 am).

The sentence can be used in the evening, after the end of the day, if the shop is still open, but not if it has closed.

Using "for" is a little more formal, but in most situations it is unnecessary.

Comment: thanks but here using "for" will be different,right? "I have eaten burgers the whole day= (I ate burger the whole day). But " I have eaten burgers for the whole day)=( I ate burgers the whole day ago)

Comment: Sometimes using “for” will change the meaning, but not in this sentence.

Comment: cheers What i understood as in meaning that "Room was painted whole day=Room has been painted the whole day=Room has  been painted for the whole day" will mean same thing.

Comment: In the burger example, the "for" also makes no difference. Either way, you are eating burgers all day. Maybe literally, you have not stopped eating burgers since you woke up this morning, or maybe not literally, you have eaten several burgers at various times of the day. But with or without "for" doesn't change the meaning.